# Finite expectation induces finite almost surely

Tags: probability, measure-theory

For a non-negative random variable, one can show with the inequality $$KP(X\geq K)\leq E[X]\tag{1}$$ that $X$ is finite almost surely. Namely, $$A:=\{X \text{ is infinite}\}=\bigcap_{K\in\Bbb Q}\{X\geq K\}:=\bigcap_{K\in\Bbb Q}A_k$$ and $$P(A)=\text{lim}_{K\rightarrow\infty}P(A_k)$$ using the continuity of $P$ and $P(A_k)$ is finite for each $A_k$.

**Question:** Is the statement true for a general random variable? Obviously the inequality (1) won't hold if one does not insist on non-negative random variable? How can I proof it?

Comment: Use $|X|$ instead: $EX$ exists iff and only if $E|X|$ exists.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks